# Laravel live project's route functionality is not working properly .... why?

Tags: php, subdomain, web-hosting, laravel-5

I have a subdomain  http://206.217.128.227/~obts/ . I hosted my laravel project on this subdomain . This domain's cpanel structer is[image: cpanels folder structures]

When I click on any href property the url is http://206.217.128.227/something
but then i have 404 error . But if I give url manually http://206.217.128.227/~obts/something then i get the correct page.
I have pasted public folder's content on public_html folder. And all other contents of project on laravel folder.
I modified index.php file as

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I added paths.php file manually and modified 'public' property as

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
```

My .env file is

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=something
APP_URL=http://206.217.128.227/

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=obts_data
DB_USERNAME=obts_admin
DB_PASSWORD=password

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Now what wrong i am doing ?

Comment: Hello, it may be my lack of knowledge, but won't all your urls will have to start with `/~obts/`, then your urls like `/something' without `obts` in the path is wrong. Moreover in laravel 5.1 the views folder are set to be inside `laravel_folder/resources/views`, if your views are anywhere else, you need to change the `view.php` file inside config folder.

Comment: yahoo i have tried this type of combinations but your suggestion worked properly and now i am done . Thanks @Rash its working .

Comment: glad to know that...just to confirm, what worked? the urls to be under `~obts` path, or the changing of `view.php`? I will put an answer accordingly.

Comment: the urls to be under /~obts/ path worked .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered by me in the comments. This little article will summarize what was asked and what was wrong.

**Question:** OP reported that he set up a new L5.2 project where his "views" folder is outside his L5.2 project structure (as shown in the image below). He modified the `index.php` file to include this `new view path`. However his URLs of type `http://206.217.128.227/something` were not working whereas URLs of type `http://206.217.128.227/~obts/something` were working fine.

**Answer:** The issue here is that his generated URLs **does not contain `~obts` in the path** and thus L5.2 was reporting errors. Pretty easy fix.

However, I would like to suggest a few things here:

1. Never show **passwords** in your questions or posts. Though not relevant here because the env file is for localhost, but still don't pots things we don't need to know.
2. The way you have included your `public_html` folder by editing the `index.php` file is **not recommended**. What will happen when you update L5.2. Chances are these files will be overwritten. The right way is to edit the `larave/config/view.php` file and change the `paths` array.
3. Do not use **unsafe characters** in your URLs e.g. `~obts` contains the unsafe character `~`. See this [article](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) for what characters are safe.